# Android OnItemClick Switch Case Toast Message

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, toast

I'm trying to make it so when the user taps an image, a Toast pops up with the relevant name. I think I need to do this with a switch statement since I have an array, but am unsure if that's actually the correct way.

Here's my code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Integer[] Family = {R.drawable.angelica, R.drawable.dad, R.drawable.enzoandbully, R.drawable.enzokathyalex, R.drawable.ernesto, R.drawable.gale, R.drawable.joel, R.drawable.lorenzo};
    ImageView pic;
    Integer member;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        final ImageView pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFamily);
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " " + (position + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show( );
                pic.setImageResource(Family[position]);
            }
        });
    }
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Family.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            pic = new ImageView(context);
            pic.setImageResource(Family[position]);
            pic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            pic.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(330,300));
            return pic;
        }
    }


}
```

Edit: Forgot XML Code:

```java
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:columnWidth="160dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFamily"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgFamily"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_row="12"
        android:layout_column="0" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Difficult to answer with incomplete code (e.g. declaration of Family array doesn't seem to be here). Just run it (on emulator, if you don't have the actual device), and see what you get.

Comment: Array is declared at the top with Integer[] Family =

Comment: Why are you using `Integer` instead of `int`?

Comment: And what you have done is correct.

Comment: @Chris S your code seems correct. You should be getting a Toast for every item click.  Also, change your Toast line to 'Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " " + (position + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show( );'

Comment: @activesince93 A mistake, that's not there anymore.

Comment: @RahulChaurasia Yeah, but what I need to do is have it display different names relating to the photo tapped. In the array are some of the names, and I need the toast to display the names relative to the photo, like "Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Angelica", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();" for Angelica, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this should work.

Create a model class that will hold the name and image of the family member like this one -

```
public class FamilyMember {
    private String name;
    private int imageResource;

    public FamilyMember(String name, int imageResource) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getImageResource() {
        return imageResource;
    }

    public void setImageResource(int imageResource) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
    }
}
```

And your activity should like this one -

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

// please use the correct R
import com.sample.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    List<FamilyMember> members = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        members = getFamilyMember();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        final ImageView pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFamily);
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                FamilyMember member = members.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, member.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show( );
                pic.setImageResource(member.getImageResource());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return members.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return members.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            FamilyMember member = (FamilyMember) getItem(position);
            pic = new ImageView(context);
            pic.setImageResource(member.getImageResource());
            pic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            pic.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(330,300));
            return pic;
        }
    }

    private List<FamilyMember> getFamilyMember() {
        List<FamilyMember> members = new ArrayList<>();
        members.add(new FamilyMember("Angelica", R.drawable.R.drawable.angelica));
        members.add(new FamilyMember("Dad", R.drawable.R.drawable.dad));
        // like the above add the family members here
        return members;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Did not use import com.sample.R; as it could not resole 'sample', but it works fine without! Thanks, I'll look over it and try it myself in the future to learn this

Answer (score 0):

```
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_add_faculty:
        // EITHER CALL THE METHOD HERE OR DO THE FUNCTION DIRECTLY
        Toast.makeText(Cureent.this,"You clicked yes button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Change according to your requirement .hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm still really new, so could you sort of explain what I replace item with and where this code goes? I sort of get what you're doing but I'm also sort of lost.

Comment: i"m working on creating my repository from where u can get complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int[] Family = {R.drawable.angelica, R.drawable.dad, R.drawable.enzoandbully, R.drawable.enzokathyalex, R.drawable.ernesto, R.drawable.gale, R.drawable.joel, R.drawable.lorenzo};
    ImageView pic;
    int member;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        final ImageView pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFamily);
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int iden = view.getId();
        switch(iden) {
        case R.id.gridView:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(position + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pic.setImageResource(Family[position]);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }


    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Family.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            pic = new ImageView(context);
            pic.setImageResource(Family[position]);
            pic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            pic.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(330,300));
            return pic;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Please comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Looks like the exact code I have haha. I need to make it so the Toast displayed is a different name depending on the photo tapped, eg. Family[0] = Angelica, Family[1] = Dad, so on.

Comment: Done some changes. SWITCH statement.

Comment: Added in, however now no toast pops up. All I can think of is making a new array of the names (string[] names = {"Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie", "Delta"})and pulling from there, but I don't know how.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Do you want to display these names?

Comment: Yes, I want the toast to display different names for different pictures tapped. Sorry of I wasn't clear about that

Comment: Checkout @Rahul 's answer.